# Type 'MongooseDocument' has no properties in common with type 'Mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

I use typescript in my koa2 project.The node environment is 8.I had installed the dt~mongoose.But when I run the project, it outputs the error:

```
typings/globals/mongoose/index.d.ts(841,9): error TS2559: Type 'MongooseDocument' has no properties in common with type 'MongooseDocumentOptionals'
```